# How to format and mount an EBS volume with puppet

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet, amazon-ec2

Here is how I do manually or from User data:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

But now I wish to do it with Puppet.
I have the volume attached at first boot:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  10G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0  10G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0  50G  0 disk
```

I can easily mount with puppet but I counldn't figure out the format.
I've tried this:

```
    lvm::volume { '/dev/xvdf':
    ensure => present,
    vg     => '',
    pv     => '/dev/xvdf',
    fstype => 'ext4',
    size   => '50G',
    }-> 
  mount { $file_root:
      device  => "/dev/xvdf",
      fstype  => "ext4",
      ensure  => "mounted",
      options => "defaults",
      atboot  => "true",
  }
```

Comment: Consulting with others I've decided to NOT format my volume from puppet because if anything goes wrong at any point I can easily wipe my entire partition. I've added the formatting as part of the Cloudformation UserData.

Comment: You have an unneeded parenthesis after `$file_root`. Are you getting a parse error with this Puppet code?

Comment: True, that's a typo which I made during posting the question.